# Why do I get different reported payer emails for the same Paypal transaction depending on where I look at?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've got a transaction where the email reported by PayPal differs depending on where I look:

a. In the IPN notification, there is one e-mail in the payer_email field.

b. If I enter PayPal, click **Transactions**, page down to the transaction and click **Details**, the email that appears is different from the one received in a)

c. If I enter PayPal, click **Transactions**, and click CSV to download a csv file, in the downloaded cvs file, appears yet another payer email, which is different from the ones in a) and b).

All emails belong to the same domain (the company of the payer), but I would like to understand how reliable is the email received in the IPN because our account system relays on the IPN email to create accounts and assign balance to them.

Comment: That's definitely odd if you're seeing 3 separate values for the same transaction.  In my experience IPN would show you the primary email on the account that paid while GetTransactionDetails would show you the actual email that was paid to, which could be a secondary address on the PayPal account.  I've never done much with CSV exports as I typically use the API so I'm not sure what you'd be seeing there, unfortunately.  That said, I would never use the email address as a unique ID, but rather the payer_id / PayerID.  This is PayPal's unique ID and never changes even if the user changes emails

Comment: OK. I cannot say without rubor that I did not know there was an API for PayPal.  I set up the IPN notifications processing when I already had a few dozen payments in the paypal account so downloading the CVS was my way to recover some data pre-IPN (only part of it, IPN has a lot more data). I did not know that a PayPal user could change their email. I still need to rely on email as account because I get also payments from share-it but the uniqueness of the PayPal ID is something I could also put in the equation with repeat customer recognition.